# Script remove multiple lines of html code

Tags: regex, powershell

I need to remove the same html code from many files. I tried to write an powershell script but its not working.

```
$htmlFiles = Get-ChildItem . *.html -rec
$old = '<form method="GET" action="http://localhost/index.php" name="head2">`r`n
                <input type="hidden" name="akcja" value="szukaj">`r`n
                <input type="hidden" name="ind" value="0" >`r`n
    `r`n
                <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="margin-left:11px" >`r`n
                  `r`n
                            SOME MORE CODE
                 `r`n
                </table>`r`n
            `r`n
    </form>'

$new = ""

foreach ($file in $htmlFiles)
{
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace $old, $new} |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
 }
```

I used so much `r`n because i have this same in html files. Maybe I need to do this with regex but regex for over 50 lines is too much for me. 
I think script is not working because whitespaces doesnt match. How to make it work?

My script runs but with no effect on a files
ps. it needs to work on windows

Comment: Use Html Agility Pack for this kind of job: http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2010/03/05/html-agility-pack-rocks-your-screen-scraping-world/

Answer (score 1):

Agree with using the here-string, but you're doing a multi-line replace.  this means you need to retrieve your HTML as a single, multi-line string and use a multi-line regex.

Does this work for your application?

```
$htmlFiles = Get-ChildItem . *.html -rec    

 $regex = 
 @'
(?ms)\s*<form method="GET" action="http://localhost/index.php" name="head2">\s*
.+?
\s*</form>\s*
'@
$new = ''

foreach ($file in $htmlFiles)
{
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath -raw) -replace $regex,$new  |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
 }
```

Comment: there's no effect with this script ;/

Comment: i'm writing a whole code fragment with \s* for white spaces and this didnt replace it. but when I use .* its working, why?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [here-string](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx) instead of inserting escaped special characters which will probably mess up your regex matching.

```
@'
<form method="GET" action="http://localhost/index.php" name="head2">
    <input type="hidden" name="akcja" value="szukaj">
...
</form>
'@
```

Of course it will only work if the exact same formatting is used in each file.